# laravel blade template not rendering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

Getting into laravel and im trying to work with blade templating but its not rendering. All my examples are coming for the laravel documentation.

**UPDATE** 

So here is my **master.blade.php file** located in **resources > views > master.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        @yield('layouts.header')
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">Test to Laravel 5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my **header.blade.php file located in view/layouts/**

```
@section('header')
    <title>cookie monster</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            display: table;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .container {
            text-align: center;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 96px;
        }
</style>
@endsection
```

when i try to render my page no styles are being added even tho i have inline css at the moment, because i'm just testing how blade template engine works.

Comment: I came over here from Google scratching my head. Turns out the file name was missing the .blade.php extension for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to be using `@include('layouts.header')` rather than `@yield`.

`@yield` is what you use on a master template to specify where content will go that you can then define on a child view.

`@include` "allows you to easily include a Blade view from within an existing view." - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

Comment: @helloworld Which view are you rendering when you load the page?

Comment: master.blade.php located in resources > views >

Comment: it's right answer, use include, and remove @section('header') and @endsection

Answer (score 0):

Your layout needs to extend something. That way it can take advantage of the defined regions in your template.

```
@extends('master')
```

Comment: this just gives me a blank white screen

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the `header.blade.php` from `master.blade.php`.
Add the following line to the first line of `header.blade.php`

```
@extends('master')
```

Then you may edit the `@yield`. The yield and the section must be the same. For example:

**master.blade.php**

```
@yield('header')
```

**header.blade.php** (use `@stop` instead of `@endsection`)

```
@section('header')
    header content
@stop
```

### pastebin.com links:

[master.blade.php](http://pastebin.com/QHXBdrtL)

[header.blade.php](http://pastebin.com/VXhFW2Es)

Comment: doing this just gives me a blank screen

Comment: where is your master.blade.php?

Comment: resources > views > master.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

layout:

```
    @yield('header')
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            @yield('content')
            <div class="title">Test to Laravel 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

now, you use in controller

```
return view('someview');
```

and view code

```
@extend('layout')
@section('header')
<title>cookie monster</title>
@endsection
@section('content')
bla-bla-bla, render me IN content section of layout
@endsection
```

and result should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>cookie monster</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            bla-bla-bla, render me IN content section of layout
            <div class="title">Test to Laravel 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in layout, if you want use not changeble content, use @include('path.to.view'), if your content changes in case of every view, use @yield, that can change some part of layout

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem where:

layouts/user-profile.blade.php

```
<body>
  @yield('main')
  @yield('footer')
</body>
```

user-profile/create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.user-profile')

@section('main')
   <!-- include a personal-info sub-section -->
   @include($templateName)
@stop

@section('footer')
  <script></script>
@stop
```

The problem was with this sub-section inheritance where the need of blade's `@parent` was needed so all of the `@section('footer')` blocks were rendered in the `@yield('footer')`

user-profile/create/personal-info.blade.php

```
@section('footer')
  @parent
  // subsection scripts
@stop
```