# Delete Multiple Record Using Checkbox But Get Error DELETE 404 (Not Found) (LARAVEL)

Tags: ajax, laravel, checkbox, delete-row

Anyone please help me, i have spent an hours to solve this but didn't solve yet. I got an error when i click delete button with checkbox. Below my Route code:

```
Route::delete('/posts/destroychecked', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'destroychecked'])->name('post.destroychecked');
```

And the following is my controller code:

```js
/* Destroy multiple data */
public function destroychecked(Request $request) {
    $ids = $request - > ids;
    Post::whereIn('id', explode(",", $ids)) - > delete();
    return response() - > json(['success' => "Postingan berhasil dihapus!"]);
}
```

And then this is my ajax code:

```js
$(function(e) {
    $('#deletedAllSelectedRecord').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var allids = [];

        $('input:checkbox[name=ids]:checked').each(function() {
            allids.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('post.destroychecked') }}",
            type: "DELETE",
            data: {
                _token: $("input[name=_token]").val(),
                ids: allids
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $.each(allids, function(key, val) {
                    $("#sid" + val).remove();
                })
            }
        })
    })
})
```

And this is my **index.blade** code:

```html
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr id="sid{{ $post->id }}">
        <td>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="ids" name="ids" value="{{ $post->id }}"/>
```

The following is my button code:

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="deletedAllSelectedRecord"><i
                class="fe fe-trash dropdown-item-icon"></i>{{ __('Hapus Semua') }}</a>
```

After all that i got error when i click delete button, please help me how to solve this. the following is the error:

```
DELETE http://upskilling.id/admin/%7B%7B%20route('post.destroychecked')%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: is your javascript you are showing in a Blade file, since you are using Blade syntax? seems not

Comment: Yap, i put my javascript in home-admin. The following is my folder structure: Resources/Views/components/admin-master-blade.php. u know master-admin the file i reload all script.

Comment: in short ... that isn't a Blade View that your javascript is in, if it was that Blade syntax would be being parsed to PHP then executed and you wouldn't have the literal string in your URL ... `%7B%7B` is `{{` URL encoded

Comment: Okay i got it, but i have input javascript code in index.blade.php but the script didn't work. As i have try the javascript code only work if i put below footer above </body> code. Any solution how can i make this code work if i put in index.blade

Comment: No is not, home-admin i use only for reload all script header and footer, then for content i use @yield to reload all in that admin-home.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you're using `@yield` wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525416/laravel-blade-template-not-rendering

Comment: Thank u for your help bro, at least i know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Bro, it's solve now, what i have done is, i only add this code `@yield('scripts')` above `</body>` in admin-master and in index.blade.php i add `@section('scripts') here javascript code @endsection`. Now it's worked perfectly, thank u so much for your help bro, without your answer surely i need long time to deal with this problem.